# How do I make a continuous loop for "confirm" alert in javascript

Tags: javascript

So I'm kinda new to Javascript, so sorry if this question sounds pretty basic. So I'm trying to make a guessing game where the computer guesses the number the user is thinking. I want to make it so that no matter how many times the user clicks "cancel" a new random number will show up until it the computer "guesses" the number the user was thinking. but i cant figure out how to make a loop out of that.

here's my code:

```
const guesser = () => {
let min = 0;
let max = 100;
let guess;

alert("Think of a number between 0 and 100");
while (min <= max) {
    guess = Math.round((min + max) / 2);
    if(confirm("is your number " + guess) == false){
       if(confirm("if your number is higher, please click 'ok'. If its lower please click 'cancel'") == false){
          if (confirm("is your number " + Math.floor(Math.random() * guess)) == true){
              alert("haha got your number!")
            }
          }
        else if (confirm("is your number " + Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + guess)) == true){
                alert("haha got your number!")
            }
       }
else {
    alert("haha got your number!")
    }
    return;

}

alert("I could not guess your number. I think you are cheating!");
  };
```

Comment: Hint: you should insert `min = guess` or `max = guess` somewhere

Comment: Hey!, thanks for the response, but I have no clue where to add that.

Comment: Don't use `== false`.

Answer (score 1):

You ask the user to tell you if their number is higher or lower than your guess, but you need to do something with that information. Specifically, if their number is greater than the current guess, increase the guess by bringing the minimum up to the current guess. If their number is less than the current guess, decrease the guess by bringing the maximum down to the current guess.

```js
function main() {
  var min = 0;
  var max = 100;

  alert(`Think of a number between ${min} and ${max}`);
  while (min<max) {
    var guess = Math.round((min + max) / 2);
    if(confirm("is your number " + guess)) {
      alert("haha got your number!")
      return;
    } else {
      if(confirm("if your number is higher, please click 'ok'. If its lower please click 'cancel'")) {
        min = guess+1;
      } else {
        max = guess-1;
      }
    }
  }
  
  alert("I could not guess your number. I think you are cheating!");
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to achieve what you're looking for:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    const guesser = () => {
        let min = 0;
        let max = 100;
        let guess;

        alert("Think of a number between 0 and 100");
        while (min <= max) {

            // initial guess
            guess = Math.round((min + max) / 2);

            if (confirm("is your number " + guess) == false) {

                if (confirm("if your number is higher, please click 'ok'. If its lower please click 'cancel'") == false) {
                    // number is lower than guess
                    max = guess;
                } else {
                    // number is higer than guess
                    min = guess
                }

            } else {
                alert("guessed your number!")
                return
            }
        }
    }
    guesser();
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World!
    </body>
</html>
```